# How to check if the same intent was already started?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, dialog, cloud

I have crated a dialog activity which pops up when my application receives a message from the cloud, prompting the user to take an action (pressing yes/no). But if there are to notifications in the same time, the new dialog intent overlaps the first, and if the user selects either yes/no, a 3rd activity is started and the first dialog is lost.

Is there a way of checking if my dialog intent is already started? So I can get back to the first dialog before starting the 3rd activity which displays the full message?

Regards!

Comment: What you should do is hold an instance of that DialogActivity within a ParentActivity and check if the DialogActivity is null whenever a notification is received. e.g. if(mDialogActivity == null).

Alternatively, you can have a boolean value that checks if the Activity is running: static boolean isActive = false; and set it to true/false in the onStart/onStop methods.

Comment: So, you want to display only the first dialog if there are two dialogs?

Comment: and is your display thing happens from the current running activity or it's displayed by a running thread?

Comment: The dialog intent closes and passes the "message" to the 3rd "results" activity when OK is pressed. I need to create a condition like: "If the same activity was started (an earlier dialog with another message) "don't launcg the 3rd activity just close the current dialog" then after all the messages were read, on pressing ok launch the 3rd activity to show all my messages. @MuhammedRefaat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a `static boolean` which holds the **all messages read** status and an index of the **number of displayed dialogs**, So, when that number reaches zero, the `boolean` becomes `true` and the third activity can be displayed then:

```
public static boolean all_msg_read = true;
public static int msgs_num = 0;

// So, when a dialog displayed
public void display_dialog(){

  all_msg_read = false;
  msgs_num ++;

  // display the dialog
  // provide an onClickListener to the dialog buttons, let's suppose it's called button_pressed
}

public onClickListener button_pressed = new onClickListener(){
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           // do whatever processing you want
           msgs_num --;
           if(msgs_num == 0){
              all_msg_read = true;
              // launch the 3rd activity
           }

        }

    };
```

Comment: inform me if you want any clarification

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is hold an instance of that DialogActivity within a ParentActivity and check if the DialogActivity is null whenever a notification is received.

**Example:**

```
if(mDialogActivity == null){
     //toDo 
}
```

Alternatively, you can have a boolean value that checks if the Activity is running:

```
public static boolean isActive = false;
```

And set it to true/false in the onStart/onStop methods.

Then, you are able to check if the Activity is running like so:

```
if(mDialogActivity != null && mDialogActivity.isActive){
    //toDo
{
```

Comment: Because I call the same activity (dialog) when a new message arrives,  mDialogActivity is always true. I cannot check against boolean values. :( I may try wit a pref file, setting a variable to "true" when onCreate and back to "false) on activity finish.